# Need SQL query for the given scenario

Tags: mysql, plsql, isql

Could you please help to get this sort it out?  I need SQL query for below requirement.

I have three tables below.

Table1

```
--------
ExNo | ExTyp
-------------
1000 | CONT  
2000 | REPO  
3000 | COMD  
4000 | CONT
```

Table2

```
------
ExNo | ExTyp
-------------
1000 | RVRP  
2000 | COMD  
3000 | CONN
```

Table3

```
-------
ExCode| ExTyp | ExDesc 
-----------------------
ExTyp  | CONT   | Contain  
ExTyp  | COMD   | command  
ExTyp  | RVRP   | Reverse Post  
ExTyp  | CONN   | Connection  
ExTyp  | REPO   | Re Open
```

Main table is Table1. So my requirement is just need to print the Table3.ExDesc with Table1.ExNo based on Table1.ExTyp=Table3.ExTyp

2nd condition, if Table1.ExTyp=CONT(Only for this CONT), then I have to go to Table2 and get the corresponding Table2.ExTyp bases on ExNo match then get the Table3.ExDesc for Table2.ExTyp. (Example of ExNo: 1000)

3rd Condition, Incase the Table1.ExNo not present in Table2.ExNo for ExTyp = CONT, then I should print same CONT ExDesc in Table3 which is ExDesc="Contain" ( Example of ExNo: 4000)

Needed Example results set:

```
ExNo | ExDesc
---------------
1000 | Reverse Post  
2000 | Re Open  
3000 | Command  
4000 | Contain
```

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can left join your table2 with table1 and conditionally join the table3 with it.

```
select t1.ExNo,
    t3.ExDesc
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.ExNo = t2.ExNo
join table3 t3 on t3.ExTyp = case 
        when t1.ExTyp = 'CONT'
            and t2.ExTyp is not null
            then t2.ExTyp
        else t1.ExTyp
        end
order by t1.ExNo;
```

Produces:

```
ExNo    ExDesc
--------------------
1000    Reverse Post
2000    Re Open
3000    command
4000    Contain
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/DQT45032)

Comment: Thanks GurV. It works fine. Just small addition in this.                                

Incase Table2 having Duplicate records, I need to print only one from that ExNo match. to say simply, Same results set for below table records.

Table2
------
ExNo | ExTyp
-------------
1000 | RVRP    
1000 | RVRP    
2000 | COMD    
3000 | CONN

Comment: @user7392087 - Just put `distinct` after `select`.  See this demo - http://rextester.com/AXE1656

Comment: Thanks @GurV  

I have altered you Query for my usage. But its giving error as below  

`select distinct t1.ExNo,
    t3.ExDesc
from table1 t1 t1, table2 t2,table3 t3 where 
t1.ExNo *= t2.ExNo and 
t3.ExTyp = case 
        when t1.ExTyp = 'CONTNR'
            and t2.ExTyp is not null
            then t2.ExTyp
        else t1.ExTyp
        end;`
  
**Getting below error:** The table 'table2' is an inner member of an outer-join clause. This is not allowed if the table also participates in a regular join clause.  
  
Can you please correct and provide the sql in above format.

Comment: @user7392087 - you modified the query incorrectly. Use it as is. See in the demo that it is working fine. Also, it seems you are trying to change explicit join to comma based join - **not a good idea**.

Comment: Can you provide same sql logic with **Non-ANSI**  format?

Comment: @user7392087 - Why would you want *NON-ANSI* format? The ANSI one is way too clear and modern. The comma based join are so last decade.